# How to provide access to a UIApp for limited number of people?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want my UiApp (GAS) application accessible **only** by people I explicitely invite.
I don't want to publish my application for public access, but prefer to provide some people a link (desktop shortcut) to an html file on a shared disk (so I only need to update the link to my application if I update it).

While trying to achieve that, I experience several problems.

**Problem-1**
I don't want the user being able to see my code.
How can I achieve that?

**Problem-2**
If I execute the application as **me** I can't retrieve the actual user (Session.getActiveUser() and Session.getEffectiveUser() both return 'me') and because of that I don't know what emails nor calendar to display.
How can I retrieve info that allows to display emails and calendar of the actual user (so NOT 'me') ?
Even if this requires an extra parameter while starting the application, it's acceptable to me.

**Problem-3**
I noticed that if the project uses a library, the application won't run unless the user explicitely defines the library himself. To me it seems the user should have nothing to do with that. How can avoid this problem (apart from not using libraries)?
In my case, I use a library for logging some info. This library is not located on a shared disk. Even if I disable the library (so logs will go to the system default logger) the application fails to run as a message appears stating the library is missing (and reffered in 'Resources').
What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: It sounds like this is a container-specific project, rather than a webapp - spreadsheet app perhaps?

Comment: @Tim:  what makes you think that?

Comment: webapps don't have the code exposed AFAIK

Comment: not necessarily indeed unless the script is shared. Thanks for answering with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is rather long to answer but I'll try to make it short :

1. You don't need to share the code, keep it private.
2. The webapp should be deployed as "the user executing the app" so that all calendars, docs etc will be those of the user.   You should allow anybody to access the app and create a login identification in your app itself : when the user tries to run the app you get his email (getActiveUser()) and compare this email with a list stored in scriptProperties.  If the mail is not in the list then return a message saying this user is not allowed to run the app and let the script send you an alert so you know who has tried.
3. The Library should not be an issue, I have script using libraries that work for other users without them having to do anything except authorize.

To illustrate, here is a piece of code I use to control access of a webapp :

```
function doGet() {
  var clientOK = false;
  var client = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clients').split();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Order form').setStyleAttribute('background', 'beige');
  var mainPanel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','25');
  var reject = app.createHTML("Hello,<BR><BR>You are connected with the address <B>"+email+"</B> that is not allowed to access this form,<BR><BR>"+
                             "Please contact the webMaster if you think this is an error.<BR><BR>Thank you.").setStyleAttribute('padding','25'); 
    if(clients.join().match(email) == email){ clientOK = true ; var nom = email };
    if(!clientOK){
    app.add(reject)
    MailApp.sendEmail('myEmail@gmail.com', 'attempt to log in form', email+' tried to access the form and has been rejected. Think about asking him what happened !')
    return app
  }
 // continue normal code...
```

---

**EDIT about problem 3 :** if the Library you use writes to a spreadsheet (as a logger destination), this spreadsheet has to be shared with these users as well.  Even if they don't need to open that spreadsheet from their drive, they will be able to do it as it will appear in their 'shared with me' view in their drive. That said, maybe you can get rid of that as soon as the development phase is over ?

Comment: I have a list of members I retrieve from a contcactgroup defined for this purpose and I check against those members. So basically the same idea. I don't know how to keep the code private. It only works if I share the script and provide EDIT access to it. That is not what I intend to do. I also tried to start it using an html-file stored local and/or on the google drive. So I need to go step by step. First : how to make my code private?

Comment: Just don't share it .It does not interfere with the ability to run the webapp. If you meet problems then it means your app accesses some documents that have to be shared as well (share to anyone with the link or specific users you know)

Comment: Is your script in a standalone script file or is it bounded to a SS or document ?  (Now I have to leave but I will be back tonight)

Comment: It is a standalone script, but I do open a spreadsheet for logging and a calendar that has been shared with all the people involved (and no others).

Comment: As I said in my answer, this spreadsheet has to be shared to anyone with the link can edit or publicly-  but the calendar is not a problem since you shared it already. It is hard to guess why it doesn't work for you without sharing the script but I am 100% sure the script must not be shared.. if you want to share the code I could answer more specifically.

Comment: Sharing the code here, isn't an option. Other possibilities : I don't mind.  In principal I could even visit you as I live just 110 km from Brussels